# Image texture not showing, but diffuse does

Tags: rendering, materials, node-editor, image

I've been playing around with nodes and the node wrangler add-on. I thought of trying to mix a diffuse shader with my image texture but it didn't work out as needed. It still shows the solid color of my diffuse but not the image. Keep in mind that both objects are unwrapped, so it should show the texture. 
[image: The cube in the middle set up]
[image: The base plat form, also UV unwrapped]

[Project file](https://mega.nz/#!VPR2EYhB)

[Textures that I used and found on poliigon.com](https://mega.nz/#F!kTAFXAQA)

Other posts I've looked around didn't get me the answer.
All help would be appreciated to a new user like me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a Shader node between the Image Texture and the Mix node - in your case probably a Diffuse Shader - alternatively use a MixRGB Color node to mix the colors before feeding into the existing Diffuse shader. As a general rule you should normally connect sockets to only the same color - in your case you have a yellow (Color) connected to green (Shader) and this is the cause of your problem since green sockets should only **ever** connect to green (anything else is completely incompatible).

Note that there are some situations where you can mix *some* node types - eg, the Color of a Texture to a Factor of a Mix node. However, this does result in some conversion between the types which can produce unexpected results. There is no such conversion to or from green sockets.